# Fitting en ellipse to data and finding the vertices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, matlab

I'm using the technique described in [Direct Least Square Fitting Of Ellipses](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ellipse-pami.pdf) to fit an ellipse to a data set. This method works very well and I end up with the parameters for the conic formula:

Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0

From here I can calculate the center of the ellipse with
Xc = (BE - 2CD)/(4AC -B^2), etc...as described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections)

How can I calculate the vertices of the ellipse? The same Wikipedia article describes a method but I don't quite understand it. I'm basically looking for a way to find the bounds of the ellipse (so I can do things like draw an enclosing rectangle around it or something like that)

Here is my fitted ellipse and calculated center.

[image]

Comment: Explicit formulas are given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $A,B,C,D,E,F$ then you could take the implicit derivative of the equation of the ellipse. As the outer edges would have the critical vales of the derivative.

the implicit derivative is
$$-y'(2Cy+Bx+E)=2Ax+D+By$$

and has critical values when either $y'= 0$ or $y'=\pm \infty$ so when $2Ax+D+By=0$ *or* when $2Cy+Bx+E=0$

The maximum values of x can be found by substituting $2Cy+Bx+E=0$ which is equal to $x=-\frac{2Cy+E}{B}$, into the initial function of the ellipse, and the solving using the quadratic formula.

Similarly you can get maximum values of y by solving $2Ax+D+By=0$ which equals $y=-\frac{2AX+D}{B}$ and again solve by substituting into the initial function of the ellipse, and the solving using the quadratic formula.

hopefully the helps (and makes sense)

Comment: Note that the max values of $x$ and $y$ do not necessarily give you the vertices of the ellipse.

Comment: @NickD True, But it does give the bounding box where the edges area parallel to the x,y axies. And i haven't worked out a good way of getting the bounding box of minimal area.

Answer (score 2):

Given the real parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, the Cartesian equation:

$$
a\,x^2 + b\,x\,y + c\,y^2 + d\,x + e\,y + f = 0
$$

represents a generic *conic* in the $\left \langle x,\,y \right \rangle$ plane.

In particular, defined the cubic, quadratic and linear invariants:

$$
i \equiv -\frac{1}{2}\det
\begin{bmatrix}
2\,a & b & d \\
b & 2\,c & e \\
d & e & 2\,f \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad \quad
j \equiv -\det
\begin{bmatrix}
2\,a & b \\
b & 2\,c \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad \quad
k \equiv \text{tr}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\,a & b \\
b & 2\,c \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
if:
$$
j < 0 
\quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad
i\,k > 0
$$
this conic turns out to be a *real non-degenerate ellipse*.

In this case, a *natural parameterization* is as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = A + B\,\cos u + C\,\sin u \\
y = D + E\,\cos u + F\,\sin u \\
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \text{with} \; u \in [0,\,2\,\pi)
$$

where is it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& A \equiv \frac{2\,c\,d - b\,e}{j}\,,
\quad \quad
B \equiv -\frac{2\,\sqrt{c\,i}}{j}\,,
\quad \quad
C \equiv 0\,, \\
& D \equiv \frac{2\,a\,e - b\,d}{j}\,,
\quad \quad
E \equiv \frac{b}{j}\,\sqrt{\frac{i}{c}}\,,
\quad \quad
F \equiv \sqrt{\frac{-i}{c\,j}}\,.
\end{aligned}
$$

At this point it's necessary to make it clear what we're interested in.

---

If we were interested in the *coordinates of the vertices* of this ellipse, they're determined by minimizing and maximizing the distance function between a generic point of the ellipse and the center of the ellipse, i.e.

- if $b = 0$, the two pairs of vertices are identified by the following angles:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  & u_1 = 0\,, \quad \quad u_2 = \pi\,; \\
  & u_3 = \frac{\pi}{2}\,, \quad \quad u_4 = \frac{3\,\pi}{2}\,;
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- if $b \ne 0$, the two pairs of vertices are identified by the following angles:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  & u_1 = \arctan(z^+)\,, \quad \quad u_2 = \arctan(z^+) + \pi\,; \\
  & u_3 = \arctan(z^-) + \pi\,, \quad \quad u_4 = \arctan(z^-) + 2\,\pi\,;
  \end{aligned}
  $$

where is it:

$$
z^{\pm} \equiv \frac{-\left(B^2-C^2+E^2-F^2\right) \pm \sqrt{\left(B^2-C^2+E^2-F^2\right)^2 + 4\,\left(B\,C + E\,F\right)^2}}{2\left(B\,C + E\,F\right)}\,.
$$

---

Instead, if we were interested in the *coordinates of the extreme points* of this ellipse, they're determined by minimizing and maximizing respectively the abscissa and the ordinate of a generic point of the ellipse, i.e.
$$
u_1 = 0\,, \quad \quad u_2 = \pi\,; \quad \quad u_3 = 2\arctan(z^+)\,, \quad \quad u_4 = 2\arctan(z^-) + 2\,\pi\,;
$$

where is it:

$$
z^{\pm} \equiv \frac{-E \pm \sqrt{E^2 + F^2}}{F}\,.
$$

---

I wish you a good study.